# error with cast DataGridViewButtonCell to type DataGridViewDisableButtonCell

Tags: c#, winforms

I have error 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonCell' to type 'Sento.DataGridViewDisableButtonCell'.'

My goal is that when the checkboxcells are checked, the button will enable

My code:

```
private void GrdSento_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(GrdSento.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Check")
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBoxCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)GrdSento.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Check"];
            DataGridViewDisableButtonCell ButtonCell = (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)GrdSento.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Edit"];
            ButtonCell.Enabled = !(Boolean)checkBoxCell.Value;

            GrdSento.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

I copy from this link: [DataGridViewDisableButtonCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/disable-buttons-in-a-button-column-in-the-datagrid)

```
public class DataGridViewDisableButtonCell : DataGridViewButtonCell
{
    private bool enabledValue;
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return enabledValue;
        }
        set
        {
            enabledValue = value;
        }
    }
    // By default, enable the button cell.
    public DataGridViewDisableButtonCell()
    {
        this.enabledValue = true;
    }
}
```

DataGridViewDisableButtonCell has already inherited from DataGridViewButtonCell, but it still get error. Please help me.

Comment: can you provide a sceenshot of the design?

Comment: Have you created a custom column type as well ? Are you sure that when your gridview is created, the cells are DataGridViewDisableButtonCell ? [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/column-types-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Comment: Note that `CellValueChanged` is raised when the Column is first initialized, in the Form's constructor (`InitializeComponent` method). If you have created the Column in the DGV's designer, you don't have a chance to set the CellTemplate of that column before the event is raised. You need to add the Column in code (or create a Custom Column class that you can select in the DGV's designer). You could also wire the event after you have set the new CellTemplate. It could work, it may not (you might have the same problem with other events in other sections of code you insert after).

Comment: Did you add edit column in gridview by code?

Comment: I just add Edit column by DataGridView Designer not by code, Edit column is the DataGridViewButtonColumn

Answer (score 0):

In your [Form].Designer.cs file, change

`this.Edit = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn();`

to

`this.Edit = new **DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn();**`

Comment: Hi Chris and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you expand your answer a little. It would be great if you could explain how and why this answers the question?